# Using PHP_SELF in the action field of a form

Tags: php, html

I want to load the same page after the form is submitted.  So I have something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_video'])) {//go to db to delete}

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="delete_video" value="Delete" onClick="javascript:return confirm('Delete this video?');"/>
```

This doesn't work for me.  But if I remove the echo it does work:

```
<form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
```

How does this make sense?

Comment: When you remove the echo, you end up with a blank action. Blank actions point back to the same page in many browsers.

Comment: There're some edge cases there PHP_SELF is not accurate enough for a form action but "doesn't work me" is hardly useful description.

Comment: doesn't work for me: The delete_video will not work and it dumps me to my index page not the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead. This will give you the current URL, but `PHP_SELF` gives the path to file, which you don't want in this case.

Comment: Just using an empty string works as well. The browser handles this for you.

Answer (score 3):

If the `action` attribute is blank, the `form` will automatically post to the calling page / script.

So since you've removed the `echo` and there's no output, the action being blank is what's causing the form to still work.

Comment: This approach is not recommended and not browser compatible.

Comment: @SilverLight: Uhm, where did I recommend it? I answered the OP's question on why it (the form) still "works" when he removes the `echo`.

Comment: @SilverLight: Actually, in which browser(s) wouldn't it be compatible? Can you link to any test cases?

Comment: This is much better solution than approved one.

Comment: @SilverLight: Can you provide any examples of browsers that this does not work in?  I have been using this method in enterprise web applications for years, and I would be interested to know if I've been breaking them for certain users all this time.

Comment: @SilverLight: "not browser compatible" - LOL.

Comment: @drrcknlsn. Just tested it. This gives different results in IE and in, hm, normal browsers. In IE9 query string is dropped, when form is submited, in other browsers it's not. Also, older safari versions had problems with this approach. This is definetly not the best way to do this, although it will work for you in most cases.

Comment: @SilverLight: So, just to understand you fully, you down voted my answer because the OP's form that `POST`s may or may not receive `GET` requests in (allegedly) IE9 and older versions of Safari? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @stealthyninja I did not downote your post.